# CIImage returning nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a PKCanvas, what i am trying to do is to take the pkcanvas drawing that the user has made ad compare to another image.
However i keep getting `nil` returned section.
Why is this? my `drawing` and `picture` elements are returning `nil`. but my `image2` element is returning the users drawing as expected.
in the code below i am just comparing the drawing the user made against itself (just for testing purposes)
Also "nothing here" does get printed.

```
//function type for ciimage
    func featureprintObservationForImage(_ image: CIImage?) -> VNFeaturePrintObservation? {
        guard let ciImage = image else {
            print("nothing here")
            return nil
        }
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])
        let request = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()
        do {
          try requestHandler.perform([request])
          return request.results?.first as? VNFeaturePrintObservation
        } catch {
          print("Vision error: \(error)")
          return nil
        }
      }

@IBAction func finishCalculation(_ sender: Any) {
    
    //geting drawing
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theCanvasView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    theCanvasView.drawHierarchy(in: theCanvasView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    
    let image2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    
    let picture = featureprintObservationForImage(image2?.ciImage)
    let drawing = featureprintObservationForImage(image2?.ciImage)
    

    var distance = Float(0)
        
        do {
            try picture!.computeDistance(&distance, to: drawing!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    
        print("picture to drawing")
        print(distance)

}
```

Comment: Is image2.ciImage `nil` to begin with ?

Comment: Yes, then it changes to the users drawing that they make using pkcanvasview. The problem seems to be the “picture” and “drawing” images. Because image2 does link to the users drawing no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: For now just one but I cannot explain it fully as I did have similar issues a while back. I remember reading somewhere that if a UIImage was initialized using ciImage, and later on when you try to get a ciImage, it returns nil. Sometimes it is not apparent that happens but under the hood this could also take place. I feel I had a similar issue once before and I ended up using CGImage representation of the image than CIImage which was fine for my purposes.

Comment: Oh no this seems like it’s not going to work so , probably abit too advanced for me unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe try this to see if any difference. Convert image2 into a CGimage and convert that into a CIImage. Here is the reference: http://wiki.hawkguide.com/wiki/Swift:_Convert_between_CGImage,_CIImage_and_UIImage - does it give you anything different ?

Comment: thanks so much, it was a one line fix, i can't believe it, i was pulling my hair out. thanks for this, much appreciated. var ciImage = CIImage(image: image2!)